# Ajax. Loading json data through $.ajax() function based on Element ID

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, json

First and foremost this is a class assignment. so I have to go about it a certain way. I need to use the $.ajax() function to process the results from the php file and then load it into a "results div". What I am trying to do also is grab the ID of the clicked element with Ajax then send it to the php file and from there create a variable with the element ID and then use PHP's switch case to load a different message based on the element that was clicked.

I can get an echo with the json results.

Here is my HTML:

```
<a href="#" id="btn1" value="btn1">Button 1</a>
<a href="#" id="btn2" value="btn2">Button 2</a>

<div id="results"></div>
```

Here is my jquery:

```
$('#btn1').click(function() {
  $.post("process.php", { id: $(this).attr('id') }, function(response) {
    alert(response);
  });
});
$('#btn2').click(function() {
  $.post("process.php", { id: $(this).attr('id') }, function(response) {
    alert(response);
  });
});
```

Here is my PHP:

```
if (isset($_POST['id'])) {
  $id = $_POST['id'];
}

switch($id) {
  case "btn1": 
    $message = "btn1 was clicked";
    break;
  case "btn2": 
    $message = "btn2 was clicked";
    break;
}


$json = '{
  "result":"true",
  "message":"' . $message . '"
}';

echo $json;
```

Again that will echo the json response.

Button 1 click:

```
{
  "result":"true",
  "message":"btn1 was clicked"
}
```

Button 2 click:

```
{
  "result":"true",
  "message":"btn2 was clicked"
}
```

What I wan't to do is load the results of the json data into an element with the id of "#results" using $.ajax().

So when I try:

```
$('#btn1', '#btn2').click(function() {
    $.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      data: $(this).attr('id'),
      url: 'process.php',
      dataType: 'json',
      success: function(data) {
        var $results = $('#results');
        if(data.result == "true"){
          $results.html(data.message);
        } else{
          $results.html("Sorry, your request produced an error");
        }
      }
    }); //end ajax
  }); //end click
```

This gives me nothing. I am new to Ajax so I might be missing something. But for the class I just have to be able to click a button and have it load a message from PHP and return it back to a div id="result". But what I am trying to do is have multiple buttons you can click and based on which one you click it will give a different response. If there is a much simpler way of doing this let me know. But I have to use the $.ajax() function.

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to send the data in key/value form

```
data: {id: $(this).attr('id')},
```

Also your selector is incorrect, it should be a single string with a comma separating the individual selectors

```
$('#btn1, #btn2')
```

Comment: Good spot re. the format of the data attribute, +1.

Comment: Dammit....That did it. I new I was missing something simple like that with Ajax. The jQuery selectors were my fault. I should know better than that. You just saved my ass. Thank you for the quick response and the help. That was awesome. I just learned something I will never forget... :)